# Understanding the advantage of formulating $y=ax+b$ in $y=ax$?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, linear-model

Firstly I would like to point out that this is the question extended from the original question posed by `Abhinav Gupta` in the link [Understanding linear projection in "The Elements of Statistical Learning"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/185634/understanding-linear-projection-in-the-elements-of-statistical-learning).

Here is the summary:
Confusion starts at the page 11-12 in the book *The Elements Of Statistical Learning*, where the authors present linear expression of the form
$\hat{y} = X^T\hat{\beta}$ including the constant variable 1 in $X$ and the intercept $\hat{\beta}_0$ in the vector of coefficients $\hat{\beta}$. They went on to claim that the hyperplane includes the origin and thus it is a subspace when the constant is included in $X$.

It wasn't at all obvious to me how it goes through origin until I think outside n-dimension(n being the number of input variables) and add one dimension, therefore (n+1)-dimension and everything became clear; namely, if we can add one more degree of freedom, say $x_0$, to our input space we can show that the hyperplane going through the intercept is the special case where $x_0=1$ and it goes through the origin when $x_0=0$.

(`gril`'s visualization in the link above will give you a clear mental picture.)

Then my question is,
well ok I get how it can be thought of as a subspace but I am still missing 'why' answer. Is there a technical advantage if we formulate it in such a way? Like, in terms of computation for example? Or is it just a matter of conceptual ease with which we can deal with usual linear form?